# ProgrammingError in Snowflake query

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a DAG which executes a snowflake sql statement inside a function. The SQL is an insert statement inserting records from one table to another. While inserting, some of the records in source table are faulty and are not inserted into the target table. This is causing the insert process to fail.

Requirement:

1. I would like to skip the faulty records and load the next record from source to target tables.
2. I would like to write the faulty records to a file in GCS bucket.

   ```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators import python_operator
    from datetime import datetime
    import logging
    from my_folder import param_file
    from snowflake.connector.errors import  ProgrammingError

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    args = {
        "owner": "test_dag",
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 3, 2, 10, 1),
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['mymailid@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True
    }
    cur = param_file.cur ## param_file is a python file that contains the connection details to Snowflake
    query = """insert into employees(first_name, last_name, workphone, city,postal_code)
      select contractor_first,contractor_last,worknum,null,zip_code from contractors"""

    def run_sql(**context):
        try:
            cur.execute(query)
        except ProgrammingError as db_ex:
            print(f"Programming error: {db_ex}")

    with DAG(
        dag_id="EXCEPTION_testing", schedule_interval=None, max_active_runs=1,catchup=False,default_args=args) as dag:

        task1= python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='snowflake_query_execution',
        python_callable=run_sql,
        dag=dag)
   ```

I have tried using try and except but the task is raising an exception for faulty records and not processing the next records from the source tables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to look on `COPY INTO` statement. It has configuration of `RETURN_FAILED_ONLY=True` and `on_error=CONTINUE` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: But my sql query is an insert statement with xml decoding. My source is raw xml data and in the insert statement we are splitting xml data into columns.

Comment: So you will need to code your solution on your own. One possible option is to scan the file in advance and remove unaccepted values before you try to insert them to the DB.

Comment: Use a separate python file for the code, other than the DAG. There just catch the exception that you want to catch here, do not raise it. Although Raise the exception for other cases, or else you won't be able to record your failures.